# Image(jpg) files which are included in css file are not loading in Django 2.1

Tags: python, css, django

I  included image(jpg) files in CSS file. CSS File stored in static folder(static/myapp/css) and image files stored in same static file(static/myapp/img).

my Project Structure like this:

[image: folder structure]

settings.py

```
"""
    Django settings for svcomforts_1 project.

    Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.4.

    For more information on this file, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

    For the full list of settings and their values, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
    """

    import os

    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = '6-eaqeuu+yem7w01f=ih^!298qnmjr0e!agu=c357au02^j+1('

    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'myapp1',
        'myapp2',
    ]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_website.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]





     WSGI_APPLICATION = 'my_website.wsgi.application'


        # Database
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

        DATABASES = {
            'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
            }
        }


        # Password validation
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

        AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
            {
                'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
            },
            {
                'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
            },
            {
                'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
            },
            {
                'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
            },
        ]


        # Internationalization
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

        LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

        TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

        USE_I18N = True

        USE_L10N = True

        USE_TZ = True

        STATIC_URL = '/static/'

     """
```

style.css 1,312-322 lines

```
{% load static %}

.bannercontainer {
    position: relative;
height: 100vh;
text-align: center;
background-image: url("{% static"/img/bg1.jpg" %}");
color: #fff;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

I tried like this also  background-image: url("svcspg/img/bg1.jpg");
nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this way in your template css:

```
background-image: url("{% static "myapp2/img/bg1.jpg" %}");
```

Since, as I see, you left out ‘myapp’ from your first example in your css, and you left out static from your second example.

Or if it is still not loading, then try simply with:

```
background-image: url("/static/myapp2/img/bg1.jpg");
```

Also in settings.py you can define static files directories generally like:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
]
```

Comment: @Joshua - is it still not getting the background image?